# Django Naturaltime is not working in .annotate

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-annotate

Here I just wants to annotate a field on a model that gives human readable format saying how much time elapsed since it's created

```
My Model is created 30 seconds ago
```

My Model Description:

```
from django.db import models 
class MyModel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

class Meta:
    ordering = ['-created_at']

@property
def natural_time(self):
    return naturaltime(self.created_at)
```

What I did is here

```
from django.contrib.humanize.templatetags.humanize import naturaltime
from django.db.models import F
from .models import MyModel
m = MyModel.objects.annotate(timesincecreated=naturaltime(F('created_at'))
print m.values('timesincecreated')
```

on this print call I am getting the `DateTimeField` that I used in the model.
But If I want to access the property.

```
from .models import MyModel
m= MyModel.objects.first()
print m.natural_time
```

It works.

Any help? TIA.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use `naturaltime` function for `annotation`, `annotation` is a computation that is done on database level.

Django provides only a set of basic computations which can be processed by the database like `Count, Sum, Min, Max`, etc. You can refer to [official doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/expressions/) to learn more about `Query Expressions`.

Comment: Yes I discovered it later.I guess I would be passing the date as it is. I think I should be using ```moment.js``` for frontend to do that.

Comment: you can pass as date then use either `naturaltime` or `timesince` in your template, no need do it in javascript.

Comment: I am just building REST Api. And the frontend is using other framework. so.. I guess that's the only solution I can have.